# Can't link CSS to JSX while using Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, jsx

So, I'm pretty new to React and I'm doing a group project. I was following along some tutorials online and was able to get everything working fine, starting from scratch and working on my own.

However, in the group project, we cloned a repo that uses webpack, and are starting with that template. When I tried to copy and paste all my working code from my own project into the group project, I can't seem to link the CSS to the JSX anymore.

I've been Googling for hours and I'm sure it's something to do with webpack, as I hadn't been using that on my own version. I've tried a few things but just don't know how to fix it.

I'm also posting the webpack.config.js file. (This file was just included in the cloned repo, and I'm afraid to tinker with it too much).

Can anyone help me, please? I can't embed images yet because I've just signed up, but here is a link to pics of the error I get, and my file structure. I've tried moving the CSS into the same folder as the JSX and changing the file path, but to no avail.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOwHZ.jpg

````
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist');

var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/components/index.jsx',
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx$/,
      loader: 'babel',
      include: APP_DIR,
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    },{
      test: /\.css$/,
      loaders: [
        'style?sourceMap',
        'style-loader!css-loader',
        'style!css'
      ]
    }],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    }
  },
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};

module.exports = config; ```
````

Comment: I think the link should be import ‘../../../public/styles.css’

Answer (score 0):

I would try going up one more directory:

Try:

```
import "./../../public/styles.css";
```

Also a tip for importing with React, always start the path with "./" since this will take your current directory into consideration. "/" will search immediately in your public folder.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I've tried changing the file path in many different ways. Even when I put the CSS in the same folder as the JSX file, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try 'use' keyword instead of loaders as shown below?

```
{ test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] }
```

Comment: Just tried that, unfortunately the same error persists.

Comment: I assume that if the css file is not parsed, the styles won't be applied.You shouldn't be getting an error. Do you mean that styles are not applied?What is the specific error that you are getting related to CSS?

Comment: so when I take out line 3 in my index.JSX file, and then do "npm start", the page loads in the browser, but without any styling.  

Then when I include line 3, I get the error that the CSS module can't be found.

Comment: Can you put the styles.css in App folder same as its index.jsx and then import it as ```import './styles.css'``` in index.jsx and try?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for trying to help with this. I've got it sorted.

So I also have an index.ejs file that everything runs through and I had to link the CSS like this in it's  section.

`link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css"`

as I also have an app.js file that says  `app.set('public', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));`